# How can I fetch the lastest entry of a model new put into NDB?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

How can I get the latest entry of a model new putted into  NDB?

1: If I use a same parent key ? How to ?

I see the document write

> Entities whose keys have the same root form an entity group or group.
>   If entities are in different groups, then changes to those entities
>   might sometimes seem to occur "out of order". If the entities are
>   unrelated in your application's semantics, that's fine. But if some
>   entities' changes should be consistent, your application should make
>   them part of the same group when creating them.

Is this means , with the same parent key the order is insert order?

But , how to get the last one ?

2: If I not use a same parent key (the model is same)? How to ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're OK with eventual consistency (i.e. you might not see the *very* latest one immediately) you can just add a DateTimeProperty with auto_now_add=True and then run a query sorting by that property to get the latest one. (This is also approximate since you might have several entities saved close together which are ordered differently than you expect.)

If you need it to be exactly correct, the only way I can see is to create an entity whose job it is to hold a reference to the latest entry, and update that entity in the same transaction as the entry you're creating. Something like:

```py
class LatestHolder(ndb.Model):
    latest = ndb.KeyProperty('Entry')

# code to update:

@ndb.transactional(xg=True)
def put_new_entry(entry):
    holder = LatestHolder.get_or_insert(name='fixed-key')
    holder.latest = entry
    holder.put()
    entry.put()
```

Note that I've used a globally fixed key name here with no parent for the holder class. This is a bottleneck; you might prefer to make several LatestHolder entities with different parents if your "latest entry" only needs to be from a particular parent, in which case you just pass a parent key to get_or_insert.

Comment: Another benefit to having an indexed auto_now_add=True field is to facilitate downloading the data. We use this a lot for data that needs to be stored in a business intelligence database. You can spread the downloads over time very easily with great control. Sort of a query cursor managed client-side. Hate having to dedicate an index for things such this, but we like this set up, and use it a lot. HTH.